# PHP time of day rounding

Tags: php, date, time, rounding

I have difficulties with rounding time in PHP.

What I would like is to generate a number that would be based on the current date, but correspond to the closest "3 hour interval" in the future.

It is difficult to explain, best will be to give examples:

Current date time (as YYYYMMDDHHMM)= 201506021026

Result: timestamp of 201506021200

or

Current date and time = 201506021825

Result: timestamp of 201506022100

In other words, I always need a timestamp of the closest future value of either 0AM, 3AM, 6AM, 9AM,.....21PM.

And if the time is already past 9PM, then it woult be the timestamp of next day 0AM.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp = time();
$threeHours = (3 * 60 * 60);
$timestamp += $threeHours;
$reminder = $timestamp % $threeHours;
$timestamp -= $reminder;
```

If you would like to find closest "3 hour interval" in the past just do not add `$threeHours` to `$timestamp`;

I've prepared a snippet that takes into account time zones: http://3v4l.org/XOXMM

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong, there is no interval, it's speaking about getting close %3 time, like 6 pm, 9 pm, and then start intervaling.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it is in brackets, just like the question author asked. But really it rounds it to the nearest hour dividable by 3. Check out a snippet.

Comment: Great solution, just have to add iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    // find next hour accurate timestamp
    $hour = date("G");
    echo "hour: $hour <br />";
    if ($hour <= 21) {
        echo "still today...<br />";
        for ($hour; $hour <= 24 ; $hour++) {
            if ($hour %3 == 0) {
                $close = strtotime("$hour:00:00");
                echo "close hour: ".$close ."<br />";

                // now from $close str time add 3 hours
                for ($need =1; $need <= 12; $need++) {
                    $t += 3600*3;
                    echo date("y/m/d G:i:s" , $close + $t) . "<br />";

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "finding tomorrow...<br />";

    }



    $next = strtotime("6 hour");
    echo date("y/m/d G:i:s" , $next);

    echo "<br />";
    echo date("y/m/d G:i:s");
```

result:

```
hour: 19 
still today...
close hour: 1433278800
15/06/03 0:00:00
15/06/03 3:00:00
15/06/03 6:00:00
15/06/03 9:00:00
15/06/03 12:00:00
15/06/03 15:00:00
15/06/03 18:00:00
15/06/03 21:00:00
15/06/04 0:00:00
15/06/04 3:00:00
15/06/04 6:00:00
15/06/04 9:00:00
15/06/03 1:52:15
15/06/02 19:52:15
```

Comment: thank you, but I probably did not make myself totally clear. I dont need the actual hour, I need timestamp of that moment in the future, so the standard datetime PHP object of that moment, which I can then further work with (adding further hours etc.). I think it corresponds to the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970.

Comment: try adding your time stamp, `$hour = date("G" , time()+36000)` can help you

Comment: I dont think you understand what I need, so, if for example it was now 2nd July 2015, 15:45
Then I need timestamp of 2nd July 2015, 18:00. I dont want just to echo the hour. Or if it was now 22.40 already, I need timestamp of tomorrow midnight (hour and 20 minutes from that moment)

Comment: I got you this way, are you adding only hours to your current time? or it will be an constant difference in your time?

Comment: Well, what I need is to create an array with timestamps in the future. So for example, now it is say 21.20. So I need an array of timetamps tommorrow 00:00AM, 03:00AM,etc. (20 intervals). So basically my idea was to get the first one and then get the other ones simply by adding 3*60*60

Comment: I probably got you now, if it's 2 AM now, find 3AM,6AM,9AM if it's 9:20 PM, it should find 0 AM , 3AM + their timestamp?

Comment: I made first portion after 30 minutes working on strtime. is it?

Comment: greate challenge by the way

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by -
(1) Convert your datetime string to a php `DateTime` object, using [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
(2) Get your time.
(3) Check if it is over `21:00`(`9:00pm`) and if so move to next day and set time to `00:00`.
(4) If not over `21:00`(`9:00pm`), then divide the time by `300`(3 hr increment), use `ceil()` to round up to the next whole number, and then times  by `3`(3 hr increment) to get the next block.
(5) reformat back to your datetime string format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', '201506021026');

$time = $date->format('Hi');
if($time > 2100){
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $date->setTime(00,00);
}
else{
    $date->setTime(ceil($time/300)*3,00);   
}
echo $date->format('YmdHi');
//Result: 201506021200
```

---

**edit**

from your comments to @AliTorabi, if you wanted to get 20 intervals, this can be done easily by adding a loop where you add 3 hrs

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', '201506021026');

$time = $date->format('Hi');
if($time > 2100){
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $date->setTime(00,00);
}
else{
    $date->setTime(ceil($time/300)*3,00);   
}
echo $date->format('YmdHi')."<br />"; // iteration 1
for($i=0;$i<19;$i++){ // iterations 2-20
    $date->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
    echo $date->format('YmdHi')."<br />";
}
```

Comment: @AliTorabi not sure I understand what you mean. I answered the OP's question - They wanted to round up a given datetime string to the next 3 hr increment. They gave 2 examples -> `201506021026` results in `201506021200` and `201506021825` results in `201506022100`. My code sample does this.

Comment: @AliTorabi I now see in the OPs comments to **you** that they also want to get 20 intervals after rounding up. It is not in the OP's original question, but I have edited to show that it can be done in just 3 more lines of code.

Comment: was difficult. Middle east is 1AM. It's one the question occurrence!